# Winwheel in React with image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using winwheel.js library to render a wheel in ReactJS as shown below.

I am trying to replace the wheel with an image, as shown in this very clear example in standard JS http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/examples/basic_image_wheel. However as soon as I change `drawMode : 'image'` the wheel does not render at all.

Is there something in React that I am missing? Thank you in advance

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Winwheel from './Winwheel';

function App() {

const img = require('./planes.png');
useEffect(() => {
    window.winwheel = new Winwheel({
          canvasId: "myCanvas",
          numSegments: 4,
          drawMode   : 'code',
          wheelImage : {img},
          segments   :               
            [
               {'text' : 'T-55 Vampire'},
               {'text' : 'P-40 Kittyhawk'},
               {'text' : 'North American Harvard'},
               {'text' : 'L-39C Albatross'}
            ],
          animation: {
            type: "spinToStop",
            duration: 5,
            spins: 8,
          },
        });
    }, [])


  return <canvas id="myCanvas" width="880" height="300"></canvas>;

};

export default App;
```

UPDATED CODE - wheel still not rendered:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Winwheel from './Winwheel'

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {

    window.winwheel = new Winwheel({
          canvasId: "myCanvas",
          numSegments: 4,
          drawMode   : 'image',
          segments   :               
            [
               {'text' : 'T-55 Vampire'},
               {'text' : 'P-40 Kittyhawk'},
               {'text' : 'North American Harvard'},
               {'text' : 'L-39C Albatross'}
            ],
          animation: {
            type: "spinToStop",
            duration: 5,
            spins: 8,
          },
    });

    let loadedImg = new Image();

    loadedImg.onload = function() {
      window.winwheel.wheelImage = loadedImg;
      window.winwheel.draw();
    }
    loadedImg.src = './planes.png';
  }, [])


  return <canvas id="myCanvas" width="880" height="300" ></canvas>;

};

export default App;
```

UPDATED CODE - wheel image disappears on start spin:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Winwheel from './Winwheel';
import image  from './planes.png';

function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
      window.winwheel = new Winwheel({
        canvasId: "myCanvas",
        numSegments: 4,
        drawMode   : 'image',
        animation: {
          type: "spinToStop",
          duration: 5,
          spins: 8,
        },
      });
 }, [])

 function handleLoaded() {
  window.winwheel.wheelImage = document.getElementById('image');
  window.winwheel.draw();
 }

 return (
  <>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="880" height="300" ></canvas>
    <img id="image" src={image} style={{display: "none"}} onLoad={() => handleLoaded()}/>
  </>
 )
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `winwheel.draw()` at the end?

Comment: I added it as the last line in useEffect, and got this error:

`TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or VideoFrame)'`

Comment: I updated the code in the post to include the draw function, however the wheel is still not being rendered. Anything else I am missing? Thanks again

Comment: Seems you need to wait till image loads.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code in the post. The image now loads correctly, however when I spin the wheel the image disappears - any ideas?